# LaTeX table format

Tags: tables

I'm a beginner of LaTeX, and I met a problem when I create a table. The caption is centred while the table is not. I want to put them both left.

```
\begin{table}[ht]
            \caption{matrix D1}
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
                \hline
                & a & b & c & \makecell*[c]{d} \\  
                \hline
                \makecell*[c]{a} & \color{red}0 & 1 & 100 & 10 \\  
                \hline
                \makecell*[c]{b} & 13 & 0 & 2 &100 \\   
                \hline
                \makecell*[c]{c} & 100 & 12 & 0 &3 \\   
                \hline
                \makecell*[c]{d} & 4 & 100 & 11 &0 \\   
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: You can load the `caption` package and declare (either in the preamble, if you want the same layout for all tables, or just after  `\begin{table}` if is only for this table): `\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false}`.

Comment: Matter of taste, but better and simpler leave the caption as is  and add `\centering` before of  `\begin{tabular}`.

Comment: Any news? Do you solve your problem? If not, I will suggest to close your question since then we needs more details or clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem is already solved by @Bernard comment, so off-topic suggestion. More vertical spaces around cells contents in you can add with macro `\makegapedcells`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{caption}

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false}
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\makegapedcells
    \caption{matrix D1}
    \begin{tabular}{|*{5}{c|}}
        \hline
    & a & b & c & d \\
        \hline
a   & \textcolor{red}{0} 
            & 1     & 100   & 10    \\
        \hline
b   & 13    & 0     & 2     & 100   \\
        \hline
c   & 100   & 12    & 0     & 3     \\
        \hline
d   & 4     & 100   & 11    & 0     \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text border)